# Docusaurus: how diable blog sidebar, hidden alll recent post?

Tags: docusaurus

latest docusaurus version 2.4.x

I want to configure clean blog post content.

- disable right toc in formatter, use hide_table_of_contents: true
- ...

how to disable the left recent post list

- disable th right toc in formatter, use hide_table_of_contents: true